# Designing a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to design a layout but I'd like to get it done the right way.

As of now, I have this as my layout (it's a login form):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/color_header"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_user"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_password"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbRemember"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="@string/login_remember" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_login" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the output:

[image]

It works as expected but it's giving me a `This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless` on line 29 (3rd LinearLayout).

Which is the right way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Although, this might not be a solution to your problem, it might give you a few pointers: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

Comment: @SiddharthLele thanks for your link, as I was going to use a scrollview in a near future so it is compatible with smaller screens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around @Siddharth Lele comment link, I end up having this layout which works as I want and a plus is that it is compatible with smaller devices and also with bigger devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/color_header"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_user"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_password"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbRemember"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="@string/login_remember" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_login" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you all for your answers, surely I end up learning something from them and because of that, I'll +1 every answer and the comment from @Siddharth Lele!

Answer (score 2):

Through the warning, the system just wants to say you have the space to optimize your layout code.

It's good practice to pay attention to warning .

From this below LineraLayout , you have to remove anyone linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: Yes, but I have those two layouts to have the Remember Me occupy the same width as the EditTexts and so does the login button...

Comment: set your liner layout height as wrap content and remove first linear layout.

Comment: It won't do it, as the TableRow is fixed to the top and I want my form to be centered in the screen

Answer (score 1):

use tablelayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
android:gravity="center_vertical"   
android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"                
        android:text="user_name"           
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"   
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row5"          
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"      
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:padding="8dp" 
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="remember"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row6"            
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="login"                   
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
         />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/color_header"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_user"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_password"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbRemember"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_remember"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't return the output that I want... [see this](http://i.imgur.com/HZO05.png)

Comment: Try to recompile resources, or clean whole project. It should look like on picture I've posted above.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I already found a solution to my problem using a `ScrollView`